# How to specify a password for non-interactive commands with systemctl on a remote host?

Tags: linux, systemd, authentication, systemctl

Here is what I want to do.  I have .service files for a bunch of services spread across multiple hosts.  I want to write a shell script that can start or stop all the services, without having to have root password entered for each host when the script is run.

So, for example, the script will execute commands like this:

```
systemctl -H host1 start service1.service
```

I see there is a --no-ask-password option, but that is different because instead of authenticating to the OS to run systemctl, it asks for a password (or doesn't) if the service unit requests one.

In other words, in the absence of some other authentication method that automatically authenticates the same user on a different host, I want to try to specify the password (for example if there is a -P {passwd} option).

Anyone have ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you running `systemctl -H host1` as root? Is SSH configured to allow root access on your hosts? As far as I can tell, `systemctl` connects to remote hosts through SSH and doesn't provide any authentication method on its own.

Comment: The situation is, I do not have the root password.  My account has sudo privileges, so I can do sudo - and it doesn't prompt me, just lets me in.  But I want to run this in a shell script, on a timed basis via cron job.  So it is not interactive.

Comment: I don't think `systemctl` offered any authentication methods. It relies on `ssh` and the usual way of doing what you are looking for is by setting up SSH public key authentication. Alternatively, I guess you can use `sshpass -f password_file ssh user@host1 sudo systemctl start service1.service`.

Answer (score 0):

"Putting a password on a command line" is a Well Known Bad Idea. `ssh` can handle this.

Read many of the `man` pages produced by `man -k ssh`.

Then, once you've comfortable with `ssh`, and have run `ssh-add`:

Read `man ssh-copy-id` to copy your `ssh` identity to `root` on each client node.

Now, `ssh -l root client1 systemctl ...` is a available to you.

Read `man ssh_config` to automate further.

Add aliases like

```
alias c1="ssh -l root client1"
# usage:  c1 systemctl ...
#
 alias c1sys= "ssh -l root client1 systemctl ..."
```

to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I will have to research and put some thought into this.  SSH I believe will prompt for the root password - and like I said, it is non-interactive, so I want to put it on a cron job.  What I am trying to do is time a shutdown of services prior to backup beginning, and then startup after it has completed.